# How to get the element using id or classname in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

Here is the html, I want to hide the div of card. Instead of .card what should I write

```
    <div class="card-header"> <h3><i>Topic</i></h3></div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <form>.....</form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: I want to hide the whole content of the first div. Can I do it using the classname of that div